# How to replace dot in Helm template string

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

I'm trying to replace all the dot characters in a helm template string with `\.`, like so:

```
{{- regexReplaceAllLiteral "\." "https://endpoint.index.up" "\\\." -}}
```

I want this to output - `https://endpoint\.index\.up`

This is giving me a parse error. I've tried a bunch of different combinations but nothing is replacing the dot characters. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to replace a fixed string, [`replace`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#replace) will be easier to use.  (This is one of the [Sprig string functions](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html) so it will work with other tools that also embed the Sprig template extensions.)

```
{{- "https://endpoint.index.up" | replace "." "\\." -}}
```

It doesn't look like backslash is treated specially in the replacement string argument to [`regexReplaceAllLiteral`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#regexreplaceallliteral-mustregexreplaceallliteral) so it should work so long as the replacement string argument is `backslash dot`; inside the double-quoted string syntax you need to double the backslash but you do not need to escape the period, so again `"\\."` and not `"\\\."`.